Problem involving vectors and surfaces
I was thinking that the following problem could be used to motivate math students about vectors and surfaces.
Given a surface and a function that assigns to each point on the surface a normal vector of a given length, how can I sum up all their directions, producing, a vector, whose direction is the result, and whose length is the average length of all those normal vectors?
However, it would be nice to have an example and have a solution in abstract terms to the problem in question, to, define thought flow.
Thank you for your answers.

If you  think "that the following problem could be used to motivate math students" you should have examples yourself I can't see what an "average vector" should signify or be of any use . So you should name the use, since it is your idee!
